AC Vs DC for valve filaments
Common indirectly heated valves have filament voltages of 6.3 VAC. This was supplied from 50 Hz transformer windings in mains operated equipment. Remember that the cost of rectification and filtering was high all those decades ago. AC hum was an issue for audio work. On vintage car radios the filaments were supplied with DC with spike filtering from the car battery, so AC hum was not an issue. For high end mains powered audio work supplying filtered DC for the filaments will remove hum problems and now days this is cheap.
Are there any downsides to using DC for filaments like long term electrolytic effects?

I have to say that calling it vintage is insulting, it was only 20 years ago  in any case, DC is cool, don't use ceramic capacitors in audio applications. They both lose capacitance with voltage and have piezoelectric effect.

It was common to use differential power to the heaters by using a couple of equal resistors (or a pot) with the centre to ground so that the AC to the heaters was balanced. The pot was sometimes called a "Hum-dinger".

Recent comments on another forum here: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/vacuum-tubes-dc-heaters/msg5612305/#msg5612305

@TQQQ at the risk of wandering off-topic, is that the case for all ceramic caps or just for MLCC?

@Frog It's the case for all ceramic capacitors with type-ii (high-κ) dielectrics. So, X7R, X5R, X6S, Y5V, and the other less common type-ii ceramics, but not C0G/NP0, U2J, P90, or other type-i dielectrics. Type-iis let you get much higher capacitance in much smaller packages for much cheaper, but they have some severe downsides.

I guess that you would not drive a heater designed for 6.3v AC with 6.3v DC

@TQQQ Valves in car stereos in 2004?!

@MrGerber 2 is just below 5 on the numpad. So I think it's a typo :)

@MrGerber it was a late night post... anyway, all said is true :) and also, i remember music played by electric shavers, floppy disk drives, even a giant spark. AM radio is very versatile in this sense :)

DC is fine. BTW, sometimes power was supplied by a center-tapped transformer, with the CT grounded, to reduce hum. Of course, the tubes might have mu-metal shields to reduce hum from the magnetic field of transformers, too.
